# jQuery UI Sortable with Select Boxes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI Sortable to allow ordering of list items. Each list item contains a SELECT element.

I can drag and drop the elements fine but when I click on one of the select boxes the drop-down list does not appear.

My hunch is that binding in jQuery UI Sortable is doing something to the click event bubbling which is preventing the select box from showing it's drop down list - but I can't figure out how to solve it.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li><span><select name="opt1"><option>One</option><option>Two</option></select></span></li>
  <li><span><select name="opt2"><option>One</option><option>Two</option></select></span></li>
</ul>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  $('#sortable').sortable();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replace *span* to *div* - it works!

http://jsfiddle.net/V6r2U/1/

I'm testing in FF 3.6.x and IE8

Answer (score 0):

This was seemingly due to a bug in jQuery 1.2.6 that I was using.  After upgrading to jQuery 1.6.1 it works fine - even with spans.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occured while I was using `disableSelection()` on the element. The dropdown list shows correctly  after I removed `disableSelection()`. I used jQuery 1.11.0.